# Nothing shows up in console when I try use a function on the contents of an array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program for my programming class and I'm not getting any output. It is mostly about classes and vectors. If I run the constructor (called myDairy) and call `myDairy().getDescription()` (getDescription is an inherited function in the dairy class) I get the output I want. If I assign myDairy to a vector, I don't get any output doing `basket[0].getDescription()`. I was wondering why this is and how to fix it? 
Thank you!

//main function trying to call the constructors

```
milk myMilk = milk("Strawberry ", "2%");
dairy myDairy = dairy(false);

vector<groceries> basket;

basket.push_back(myMilk);
basket.push_back(myDairy);

basket[0].getDescription();
basket[1].getDescription();
myMilk.getDescription();
```

```
//the getDescription() function

void dairy::getDescription()
{
    //check if dairy is spoiled
    cout << "The dairy in your basket is ";

    if (mSpoiled == true)
        cout << "spoiled." << endl;
    else if (mSpoiled == false)
        cout << "not spoiled." << endl;
}
```

Let me know if you need more code!

Comment: `basket[0].getDescription();` is calling the method in class `groceries` not `dairy` Dynamic inheritance only works with pointers or references.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: How would I go about storing all of the objects in a vector, if they all have different classes?

Comment: If you want polymorphic behavior, the standard approach is to store pointers, ideally unique pointers which automates destruction, in the vector. You can't store different objects in a vector since they can have different sizes and they are different. You might want to review some good C++ books. There's a number of good ones linked at https://en.cppreference.com

Comment: Alright, ill check them out, thank you!

Comment: Check out the rec here too: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: When posting questions here you should include a minimal program that demonstrates the problem you are having. You will get much faster responses because it's usually easier for people to see what you are trying to do and how it was approached.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect as some commenters are pointing out that there's some issue with inheritance.

Groceries is your abstract class. Dairy is a concrete class but you want to have a general way to reference your basket.  This can be accomplished as follows...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Groceries {
public:
  Groceries() {}
  virtual void getDescription() = 0; //must be implemented by child
};

class Dairy : public Groceries { //inherited and must implement getDescription()
private:
  bool mSpoiled;

public:
  Dairy(bool isSpoiled) : mSpoiled(isSpoiled) {}

  void getDescription() override {
    std::cout << "The dairy in your basket is ";
    if (mSpoiled) {
      std::cout << "spoiled\n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "not spoiled\n";
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Groceries>> basket;
    std::unique_ptr<Dairy> myDairy = std::make_unique<Dairy>(false);
    basket.push_back(std::move(myDairy));
    basket[0]->getDescription();

    return 0;
}
```

While this isn't the best as far as safety and smart pointers, I think this is appropriately simple...relatively :)  Thanks for posting!

::sorry I still can't comment::
edited to use unique_ptr. Thanks for the feedback doug!
edited and retested -> removed the cruft in make_unique, thanks Jonathan Geisler! That looks much better :)

Comment: It leaks memory. You should include cleanup code or better use smart pointers, not just mention them.

Comment: you do not need the call to `new` or the `Dairy` constructor inside the call to `make_unique<Dairy>` since the parameters are forwarded to the constructor for you and the dynamic memory allocation is also done for you.